What's this nugget called in these tektro drop levers?

Inside of this hole there used to be a cylindrical stopper or drift that was used to set the lever pull distance. It dropped out of this on a ride at some point and I can't find it. Since I don't know the name I can't search if the component is available anywhere.

Historically, Campagnolo brake levers or Ergopower levers used this button to open your rim brakes to make it easier to remove the wheel. I think this was only implemented in the 12s rim brake groupset, but that button is also the reach adjustment system. Shimano puts the brake release lever on the brake itself.
In situations like this, you can go to the manufacturer site, try to find the page for the master component (in this case, a brake lever). You can try to find the most similar model to what you have. For Campy and Shimano, the technical or dealer's manual may have the exploded diagram with all the part numbers, and usually the part names.
Tektro doesn't seem to have a technical manual. Here's the user manual for one of their brake levers. That manual calls it the cable release button. If you said that to a Campagnolo dealer who was fluent in English, chances are good that would convey the same message. However, their 12s components manual calls this part the pivot. Which is not really descriptive enough - do keep in mind that they're incorporated in Italy, so some things may have got lost in the translation. Anyway, if you walked into a bike store and asked,

You know the cable release button on the brake lever that Campagnolo and Tektro levers have?

The answer might well be "no, who even rides Campy anyway," or, if it's a younger sales rep, maybe "Camp a what?" But that should be descriptive enough to convey your meaning.
With Shimano, Campy, or SRAM, chances are that a dealer would know what you're talking about if you asked about a part, or they would help you look through their spare parts catalog. Or you can just Google the part name or number. Tektro is a lower-end supplier, often specced OEM. They're based in Taiwan, although there is a Tektro USA and there should be Tektro national distributors in at least some EU countries. Here's their dealer locator - Quality Bicycle Products is one of them, so any bike store should be able to order any spares that are sold. However, I couldn't see this part offered as a spare from a casual Google search. Your results may vary.
After answering, the OP mentioned they gave up and bought a pair of TRP levers - ironically, TRP is the high-end brand held by the same company that holds Tektro. TRP's site also doesn't appear to have manuals with parts and numbers. They do sell small parts for the Hylex brake levers. These are mechanical disc brakes.

Part #3 is described as "pushrod pivot pin and bushings". If the problem above happened to this TRP lever, then I strongly suspect that the replacement part is #3. Part #2 is "lever pivot pin and bushings", and this is not it. Now, I don't think that cable release button really pivots on anything, so I'm puzzled at the nomenclature. However, that part is in the right place on the brake lever, and it is indeed a little push rod. For all you know, since they have the same parent company, this part might work on a Tektro lever, but this should be confirmed with their customer service.

I've had trouble with tektro in the past. Their UK subsidiary wouldn't deal with end users, and the part that I knew existed (I had a part number from a scanned catalogue) wasn't carried by any retailers because it was meant for OEMs. I did it get it out of the bike manufacturer's spares department but they were always really hard to deal with

Likely you're right. Scrapped the levers, bought TRPs.

Interestingly enough, TRP and Tektro have the same corporate parent, with TRP being higher end.

@WeiwenNg same is true of Volkswagon and Audi :D

TRP stands for Tektro Racing Products. They are the same company/manufacturer.

When it comes to brakes, TRP products are more likely to be sold to end users, and more likely to be worth having (I have Spyres on my tandem) and spares are available.  My first experience of disc brakes was a Tektro OEM cable front brake, and I couldn't see why anyone would choose it over V brakes which had easier adjustment and more stopping power

Not really related, but while Tektro is a lower end manufacturer, you can sometimes find gems among their portfolios. The Tektro Mini-Vs were great in cyclocross if you needed mini Vs and after you replaced the stock pads - the stock pads were truly execrable, but the mini Vs were only US$17 per end.
